# find the changed properties between two objects

Tags: ios, swift, diff

I'm working on a entity diff algorithm. I'm trying to find the changed properties between two objects like a before and after. Is it possible to compare two object's value? Both of them are of type `Any` and can't be compared.

```
import Foundation

class Person {
    var gender: Gender = .female
    let dateOfBirth: Date

    init(dateOfBirth: Date) {
        self.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
    }

    class func GetDateFromString(DateStr: String)-> Date
    {
        let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)
        let DateArray = DateStr.components(separatedBy: "/")
        let components = NSDateComponents()
        components.year = Int(DateArray[2])!
        components.month = Int(DateArray[1])!
        components.day = Int(DateArray[0])!
        components.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
        let date = calendar?.date(from: components as DateComponents)

        return date!
    }

    enum Gender {
        case male
        case female
        case unknown
    }


    func update(oldValue: Person?,entity: Person) {
        if let oldValue = oldValue {
            let mirror1 = Mirror(reflecting: oldValue)
            let mirror2 = Mirror(reflecting: entity)


            for (child1,child2) in zip(mirror1.children,mirror2.children){
                if let dob1 = child1 as? Gender, let dob2 = child2 as? Gender {
                    if dob1 == dob2 {
                        print("not equal")
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

}

extension Person: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.gender == rhs.gender && lhs.dateOfBirth == rhs.dateOfBirth
    }
}




let user1 = Person(dateOfBirth: Person.GetDateFromString(DateStr: "12/1/1987"))
let user2 = Person(dateOfBirth: Person.GetDateFromString(DateStr: "10/10/1987"))
user1.gender = .male
```

Comment: Make your objects adopt `Comparable`. Btw: Please conform to the naming convention that function and variable names  start with a lowercase letter. And there is no need to use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` in Swift 3+.

Comment: I'm not sure from your full code what you're trying to accomplish. However, your cast will succeed if you just change `dob1 = child1 as? Gender` to `dob1 = child1.value as? Gender`

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is equality, you can conform to the [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) protocol. If you need greater than/less than comparisons, you could conform to [`Comparable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable).  Here's an example of how you could use equatable:

```
extension Person: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.gender == rhs.gender && lhs.dateOfBirth == rhs.dateOfBirth
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I adapt this into `for (child1,child2) in zip(mirror1.children,mirror2.children){`  ? I would like to know which property changed

Comment: You can always cast the objects to Person and then check the properties directly like `if let person1 = child1 as? Person, let person2 = child2 as? Person`

Comment: `Cast from 'Mirror.Child' (aka '(label: Optional<String>, value: Any)') to unrelated type 'Person' always fails`

Comment: If that cast always fails, then mirror1.children is not an array of Person objects. I'm not sure where your mirror1 and mirror2 are coming from, but you need to figure out where your data is before you can compare it.  When you do, casting will work.

Comment: Its a playground code. I added the entire code and updated my question. Child1 and Child2 are properties of Person struct. It still throws a warning `Cast from 'Mirror.Child' (aka '(label: Optional<String>, value: Any)') to unrelated type 'Person.Gender' always fails`